# InfluxDB How to Make a Continuous Query that Collects Stores Unique Tag Values in a Table

Tags: influxdb

I am using InfluxDb and I would like create a continuous query that can select all unique  tag combinations for that table. I have a measurement dopplerDataHistory with the tags clientID and eventID. I would like to get the clientID and eventID combinations and write them to another measurement called eventTypes.
So if I were to have

```
name: dopplerDataHistory
time                clientID eventID  lat   lon
----                -------- -------  ---   ---
1528767015010000000 Bob      Sign In  87687 665.67676
1528767015010000000 Sally    Sign In  87687 665.67676
1528767015010000000 Bob      Donation 87687 665.67676
1528767015010000000 Sally    Sign In  87687 665.67676
```

I would expect the query to write this two a the eventTypes measurement:

```
name: eventTypes
time                clientID eventID  
----                -------- -------  
1528767015010000000 Bob      Sign In  
1528767015010000000 Sally    Sign In  
1528767015010000000 Bob      Donation
```

Does Influx support this kind of functionality? I have tried getting the unique tag keys for each of the tags, but my understanding is that continuous queries in influxdb do not support SHOW statements. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time this functionality does not exist in Inlfux. I used a different database in conjunction with Influx to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  I'm looking for the very same functionality, from the sounds of it.

Comment: @Rodney Gizel I was unable to copy the tags and their unique value combinations into a new measurement, so I used couchbase instead.